# Convert list to jsons

Tags: c#, json

[image]
Hi
I have a list in my database and i want to show this in a treeview and this is my problem.
I use entityframework and can get data in list format but my componnent need json type . 
So
How can i convert this list that "category" field be a parent node and "code" field be a child node ?
Thanks

Comment: show code not pictures

Comment: So the question is how to work with JSON in C#? (hint: google "newtonsoft json"). Or do you have a particular question?

Comment: I delete my code. It's not working. This picture is my base question

Comment: What format of JSON do you want for the tree control?

Comment: @enkryptor I can work with json but i can't figure how can i do convert this table to json whit parent child format

Comment: @Iman what's the problem? Can you show an example of JSON you need?

Comment: @Richard I need the category field is parent and code filed be child node

Comment: @enkryptor I need something like this. {
    'Demo Sheet 1': [
        'Demo View 11',
        'Demo View 12',
        'Demo View 13'
    ],
    'Demo Sheet 2': [
        'Demo View 21'
    ]
} that demo1 is my category filed and demo11 or demo 12 or demo 13 is my code fileld

Comment: @Iman I can't see any "demo view" at the picture. Cmon man, you want us to write working code for you, don't be lazy, at least show us a correct example of what do you want. Posting your code that is not working would be nice too, at least we could point at what is wrong there.

Comment: Consider using LINQ GroupBy() https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: In picture ,category and code are on same level in table hierarchy.

Comment: @enkryptor this picture is from my database and the sample is only show structure . I dont want your write code for me i want hint me to get solution

Comment: @ronak patel yes this is exactly my problem . I dont know how can i seperat this level

Comment: @enkrptor  so by group by method i must run a query for any category data  ? I have a long list and it is take time

Comment: @imad, can you show me exact result you want as per your above record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically you have a collection of arrays, each represents a row in the table:

```
(1, A), (1, B), (1, C), (2, D), (2, B)
```

They can be unordered:

```
(1, B), (1, A), (2, D), (1, C), (2, B)
```

In order to serialize them into JSON, what do you want to get is:

```
(1, (A, B, C))
(2, (D, B))
```

That transformation can be done with LINQ:

```
 var structuredData = rawData.GroupBy(data => data.Category);
```

You will get an bunch of enumerable [IGrouping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977(v=vs.110).aspx) objects, where .Key() will be the Category property.

For more information, see [How to: Group Query Results](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545971.aspx)

Comment: Thanks my friend for hint . I will try . My consider is for time that spend to do this. My list is to long and i'm afride when my visitor number is grow the app what crashed